# Space time diagram for debugging in message passing parallel programs?

Tags: logical-validity

I was asked in the test to draw a Spacetime diagram for debugging in message-passing parallel programs, I want to know is this even a valid question?

Comment: In what course did you encounter that?

Comment: Parallel Computing